# MySQL Query line, 3 highest values?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a blog and I have decided to order my blog by the ID, this is because I want to display 3 on the homepage and all of them in the blog. Anyhow thats not my problem straight to the point I need help with my MySQL Query.

Say for example I have the following ID's in the Database: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

I only want to show 3, the newest 3 so  8, 9 then 10. I dont know how I'd Query this could I please ask for a Query line for my MySQL please?

I know this is a stupid question I have found example of what I mean but Its talking about adding 2 numbers together? I only need the one number placed in order.

Anyhow, thanks guys!

Comment: usually a blog is ORDER BY the time it was created, last 3 would be `ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by the ID, descending. This will place the post with the highest ID at the start of the result set. You can then use `LIMIT` to only return 3 results (i.e. the latest 3).

```
SELECT `post_id` FROM `tblName` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TableName] 
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE true ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Why the extra `WHERE` clause?

Comment: its not needed, but I like it for styling, it lets me know that I am selecting every line. Picked up the habit from phpMyAdmin which has this as the default sql query "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1".